# 404 error handle in Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa, error-handling

I am using Sitecore SXA and handling page not found through by default functionality in SXA by going on below path:

`/sitecore/content/{tenant name}/{sitename}/Settings` > Error handling tab >
and add static page url under "Page Not Found Link" textbox. It is redirecting the page to page not found and working fine but URL is not changed to our custom static page(pagenotfound) in live site.

**For example :** If we type something wrong in url then it will redirect to page not found page. However url will remain. I would like to change its URL to "page not found" as well when we redirect to "page not found"

https://sitecore.com?dhfskhfspage

[image]

Comment: What is occurring is preferred functionality. You want the 404 content (for the user) and a 404 status code + original URL (for the search engine).

Comment: What is the purpose for changing the Url? This is not a recommended way of serving 404 content.

Comment: @RichardSeal we would like to show only those url which is showing in a site. If we have page not found page then we would like to show url related to "page not found"

Comment: @JimNoellsch yes but we would like to change url as per the page showing. When we are using error handling module then it is showing page not found when something go wrong but url does not update as per the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the name of the custom error page to something else, e.g., 404-error. Sitecore has a default error page with the same name.